# Is there a way to know the offsets of interlacing blocks in image files?

Tags: image, imagemagick, png, jpeg, image-manipulation

That is, if I have `image.png` and it happens to be an interlaced image, I would like to split the file at the exact offsets where an interlacing block is present. I would like to have the same thing for progressive .jpg files.

I can read the specs and try to figure it out from there, but it would be nice if such a thing existed in e.g. ImageMagic or any other library/tool.

Comment: Would you mind saying *why* you want to do such a thing? Just being nosey :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell I can only guess why OP wants it, but I needed to extract interlace passes separately to make firefox update the display at the end of each pass (feature added to Firefox Nightly in August 2015), and to pause after each pass so I could diagnose problems.  ImageMagick doesn't directly support what OP wants.

Comment: See also the contrib/gregbook/rpng2-x demonstration that is distributed with libpng.  It has the capability of displaying an interlaced PNG image with a pause between passes.

Comment: @MarkSetchell In our [server](https://www.shimmercat.com), we want to enable showing low resolution versions of all the images early and uniformly. For that we want to be able to deliver the first few interlacing/progressive blocks of each image before any of the later ones. Like some sort of [barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_(computer_science)). The only problem is finding where in the files are the breakpoints.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Thanks for the pointer, it will come handy. And specially, thanks you for your work at Firefox, otherwise what we want to do would have less sense ;-) .

Comment: Thank you both for indulging me :-) It's good when we can all learn.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks to you for your time!