# Measure goodput before sending a response

Tags: http, networking, web, tcp, http-live-streaming

My idea is to make it possible for web applications working on slower connections to fallback on alternative smaller asset versions(like images, videos, etc.). HTTP Live Streaming has similar behavior but for video streams.

At first I thought, this can be achieved by using HTTP/2 server push. The web server would send a response, measure the goodput and push appropriate asset versions before closing the connection. But this would eliminate the advantage of the server push because the client can start downloading the assets only after receiving the page body. Since assets are not served like streams, the server should detect goodput before sending the HTTP response to the client.

I wanted also to check if I can get throughput from TCP stack, for example values from the slow-start. But I guess it would be available only upon sending the response.

Does anybody know how it is possible for a web server to measure goodput before sending a response?

Answer (score 2):

There may be other scenarios, but I can risk an answer for the case when the server sees the client for the first time.

By the time the TCP connection has been established,the server's operating system basically have one data point, given by the ACK package. I don't think it is  really possible to measure network throughput with one data point, nor goodput. And sort of intersecting those packets with raw sockets, there is no way to see their timing in the application.

Then you have the TLS hand-shake. For that one it may be possible to observe the rough timings of the packages sent and received. I say rough because once they are in the OS buffers there is no way from inside the application to know when they are actually put into the wire. And then those latencies are not related directly with goodput.

Nonetheless, I think that your idea is viable because browsers start fetching image data long after they have fetched a lot of other stuff (the .html itself, .css, javascript and even web fonts), often already out of the slow start. At that point in time there may have been opportunity to collect enough stats  to build a goodput estimate. And with HTTP/2, you can delay  sending the data a little bit if you want to be sure....

However, I would recommend against associating two different live assets with the same URL, which you would have to do in this case. Just think about it: the user fetches the image in a bad connection first, the image is cached. Next time the user connects from his docking station at home, the cached image is shown to him. Ugly! But a web application could query the server for some network goodput stats before *requesting* an asset (see? no need to use PUSH). I imagine this would be especially effective with video.

For images, you can simply use interlaced/progressive PNGs or JPEGs. We [are just building something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35308473/is-there-a-way-to-know-the-offsets-of-interlacing-blocks-in-image-files?noredirect=1#comment58350162_35308473) into [Shimmercat](https://www.shimmercat.com/) to control the priority of individual interlacing blocks. This one probably will use push....